# Proving that an element in an algebra presentation is nonzero

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, group-presentation

Let $F$ be a field, $F\langle x,y\rangle$ the free $F$-algebra on two generators (polynomials in two noncommuting variables), $A= F\langle x,y\,|\, xy\!=\!1\rangle= F\langle x,y\rangle/\langle\langle xy\!-\!1\rangle\rangle$ an algebra presentation, where $\langle\langle xy\!-\!1\rangle\rangle = \{\sum_i f_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i; f_ig_i\!\in\!F\langle x,y\rangle\}$ is the ideal of $F\langle x,y\rangle$, generated by $xy\!-\!1$.

In $A$: $yx$ is an idempotent, $x\!-\!yx^2$ is a nilpotent, $x$ is a left zero-divisor, $y$ is a right zero-divisor.

Questions: How can I prove the following claims?

1. $yx\neq0$ in $A$, or equivalently, $yx=\sum_i f_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i$ in $F\langle x,y\rangle$ cannot happen.
2. $yx\neq1$ in $A$, or equivalently, $yx\!-\!1=\sum_i f_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i$ in $F\langle x,y\rangle$ cannot happen.
3. $x\!-\!yx^2\neq0$ in $A$, or equivalently, $x\!-\!yx^2=\sum_i f_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i$ in $F\langle x,y\rangle$ cannot happen.
4. $x$ is not a right zero-divisor in $A$, or equivalently, $fx=\sum_i f_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i$ in $F\langle x,y\rangle$ implies $f=\sum_i \tilde{f_i}(xy\!-\!1)\tilde{g_i}$ for some $\tilde{f_i},\tilde{g_i}\!\in\!F\langle x,y\rangle$.
5. $y$ is not a left zero-divisor in $A$, or equivalently, $yf=\sum_i f_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i$ in $F\langle x,y\rangle$ implies $f=\sum_i \tilde{f_i}(xy\!-\!1)\tilde{g_i}$ for some $\tilde{f_i},\tilde{g_i}\!\in\!F\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: John's given a great answer, but here's a very direct method for 1: assume that yx = 0. Then, by right-multiplying by y, we see that y = 0; and by left-multiplying by x, we see that x = 0. Now 0 = xy = 1. So in fact A is just the zero ring: that is, the ideal (xy-1) is all of F<x,y>, so xy-1 was a unit in F<x,y>. That's obviously nonsense - pick your favourite reason, e.g. because of the natural $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-grading on F<x,y>. (Informally, $\deg(f) \leq deg(afb)$ for all $a, b, f$: multiplying by stuff never reduces the degree, modulo some silly discussion about what deg(0) means.)

Comment: @Billy: I don't understand your argument for $A$ not being the zero ring. What does a grading have to do with being nonzero? All steps of the grading can be $0$.

Comment: The grading is on F<x,y>. I had a specific one in mind: the natural one whose nth part is the homogeneous polynomials of degree n. (So the 0th part is F, the 1st part is generated by x and y, the 2nd part is generated by x^2, xy, yx and y^2, ...) It's easy to check that this *is* a grading. Make sense of the statement "if $abf \neq 0$, then $\deg(f) \leq \deg(afb)$".

Comment: If you prefer, think first of the commutative polynomial ring F[x,y], where this is obvious. Suppose u is an invertible polynomial, say uv = 1; then deg(uv) = deg(u) + deg(v) = deg(1) = 0, but all degrees are at least 0, so deg(u) = deg(v) = 0. In particular, deg(xy-1) = 2, so this can't be a unit. I'm just doing the same thing in the non-commutative case, a little more carefully.

Comment: At the risk of spamming, I'll make the final comment that these are not just very similar: they're actually the same argument. (The map $\varphi: F\langle x,y \rangle\to F[x,y]$ sending x to x and y to y is a ring homomorphism, and the grading I imposed on the non-commutative ring is just induced from the degree map on the commutative ring. So, in fact, you can push everything through this homomorphism, and say that if $xy-1$ could be somehow inverted, then $\varphi(xy-1)$ could too.)

Comment: Don't worry, you're not spamming :). In the commutative case, say we have the algebra $A\!=\! F[x,y|uv\!-\!1]$. You have the usual grading on $F[x,y]$, and you have $uv\!=\!1$ in $A$. When you wrote $\deg(uv) = \deg(u) + \deg(v) = \deg(1) = 0$ and $deg(u) = deg(v) = 0$, what does $\deg$ denote? The usual degree on $F[x,y]$, or some degree on $A$? How is that degre on $A$ defined? Surely it isn't inherited from the grading from $F[x,y]$, since $uv\!-\!1$ isn't a homogenous polynomial.

Comment: Forget about A for a second. The element xy-1 (in F[x,y]) is invertible if and only if there is some polynomial u = u(x,y) in F[x,y] such that (xy-1)u = 1. Now take deg (the usual degree map on F[x,y]) of both sides, to show that deg u = -2, which is impossible as u is a polynomial. So xy-1 is not invertible, and so the ideal (xy-1) is not all of F[x,y], so B = F[x,y]/(xy-1) is a non-zero ring. But if yx = 0, it's easy to see that x = y = 0, and so the ideal (xy-1) = (1) = F[x,y], and B is the zero ring. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @Billy: Yes, this argument works in the commutative case, because the ideal generated by $xy\!-\!1$ is $\{(xy\!-\!1)f; f\!\in\!F[x,y]\}$. But in the noncommutative case, the ideal generated by $xy\!-\!1$ is $\{\sum_if_i(xy\!-\!1)g_i; f_i,g_i\!\in\!F[x,y]\}$. I do not see any good argument why this ideal could not contain $1$.

Comment: If you're not content with the direct method of gradings, do it more indirectly. Let $\varphi$ be the obvious map from $F\langle x,y\rangle$ to $F[x,y]$. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $(xy-1)$ in $F\langle x,y\rangle$, and let $J$ be the ideal generated by $(xy-1)$ in $F[x,y]$. Show that $\varphi(I) = J$. (Hint: $\varphi$ just forces everything to commute, i.e. $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b) = \varphi(b)\varphi(a) = \varphi(ba)$. So $\varphi(\sum_i f_i (xy-1) g_i) = \varphi(xy-1) \varphi(\sum_i f_i g_i)$.) Now, if $I$ contains 1, then $J$ contains 1. This is a contradiction.

Comment: I would strongly suggest taking a look at Bavula's paper: [The algebra of one-sided inverses of a polynomial algebra](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0641).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[A ring element with a left inverse but no right inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70777/a-ring-element-with-a-left-inverse-but-no-right-inverse/70779#70779)" and also "[Right inverse but no left inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292527/left-and-right-inverses)." That last question was one of mine.

Note (4) and (5) are immediate since $xy=1$ in $A$ (i.e., $x$ is a left-inverse of $y$ and $y$ is a right-inverse of $x$).

For the others, the trick is to map your algebra to a concrete algebra where computations are easier. The canonical example seems to be the endomorphism algebra of a countable dimension $F$-vector space (i.e., $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty Fe_i$). Map $x$ onto the "shift left" operator and $y$ onto the "shift right" operator. Then statement (3) takes the following form: "shifting left twice and then shifting right is not the same as shifting left once."

Comment: Ah, of course, (4) and (5) are trivial. Mapping in some known algebra in which a given relation does not hold: great idea!!! I've already seen this trick, but disappointingly, it didn't stick with me. Thank you!