# the left inverse and right inverse in a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is well-known that if $R$ is an Artin ring,and $ab=1$ in $R$ where $a,b\in R$,then $ba=1a$.(This is not difficult)this is a very hot in Mathematics. [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/453628)

It seems it is not right for arbitrary ring that if $ab=1$,then $ba=1$.
Can someone helps to give an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292527/29335) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677270/29335) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/627566/29335) or any of other similar posts that show up if you just search for "[ring-theory] right left inverse"

Comment: @rschwieb thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Staying at linear endomorphisms, this is no longer true for infinite dimensional spaces. 
   Let e.g. $e_1,e_2,\dots$ be a basis, and consider $B:=e_k\mapsto e_{k+1}$ and $A:=e_k\mapsto e_{k-1}, \ e_1\mapsto 0$

2.Take any monoid $M$ that satisfies this, then consider its 'group ring' $\Bbb ZM$.