# $R$ local ring, $I$ maximal ideal then $x\notin I$ implies $x$ unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a conmutative local ring, $I$ its maximal ideal. I want to prove that  $x\notin I$ implies $x$ unit.

So far I have: Let $x\notin I$, I consider $x+I\in A/I$, which is a field (because $I$ is maximal). So there exists $y+I\in A/I$ such that $(x+I)(y+I)=1+I\Longrightarrow xy+I=1+I$. How do I deduce that $y$ is the inverse of $x$ (which I think it is true). All I have is $xy-1\in I$

Comment: You need to use that $R$ is a local ring. This isn't true, for example, for a  maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different idea.

Suppose $x \not \in I$. Then since $R$ is local, $x$ must generate $R$ (unless $x=0$). Hence there is some $z \in R$ such that $xz=1$.

Comment: I think the whole thinking part of the question is contained in that $x$ must generate $R$ since $R$ is local.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x$ is not a unit. Then by Zorns lemma there exists a maximal ideal in $R$ containing $x$. But $R$ is a local ring, so has a unique maximal ideal, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Just a side note: This is fine if the ring is commutative (which may well suffice for the OP) but the reasoning doesn't work for noncommutative rings (and the claim in the post is true for noncommutative local rings.) you can have nonunits that do not lie in any proper ideal.

Comment: @rschwieb, if $R$ is noncommutative then can't we say that the left ideal $(x)=Rx$ is a proper ideal of $R$ containing $x$? Do you mean by "ideal", being both left & right ideal?

Comment: @Ninja Yes, "ideal" means "two-sided ideal" by default. I am saying that it is possible for $Rx=R$ and $xR\neq R$ at the same time. Such an $x$ would be a nonunit such that $(x)=R$.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you, do you have an example in your mind? I am though the real quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ but could not find an ideal satisfying $\mathbb{H}x = \mathbb{H}$ and $x\mathbb{H} \neq \mathbb{H}$

Comment: @Ninja There are examples [appearing many places on the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70777/29335), one of which I'm sure is [this example at DaRT](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/15/).  $\mathbb H$ is [Dedekind finite](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/61/), so it will not be an example. You need a much more wild type of ring to get it to happen.

Comment: @rschwieb, thank you very much, I am checking the examples.

Answer (score 1):

if $x$ is not a unit, then $(x) \neq R$ and since $I$ is the unique maximal Ideal you must have $(x) \subseteq I$, which is impossible.