# We say that a ring is "local" when it has only one maximal ideal. Prove that the elements that are out of the maximal ideal are units.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have to solve the following problem:

We say that a ring is "local" when it has only one maximal ideal. Prove that the elements that are out of the maximal ideal are units.

---

I know that if $A$ is a ring and $\mathfrak{a}$ its ideal, $\mathfrak{a}$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ when it is proper and when it satisfies the following: $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{b}\subseteq A \Rightarrow \mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{b}=A $.

I have started like this:

Let we have $\mathfrak{a}$, the maixmal ideal of $A$ (the one and only). We know that $\mathfrak{a}\neq A $ and if $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathfrak{b}\subseteq A$, $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{b}=A $.

Lets suppose first that $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}$, and lets we take an element, $x$, which is in $A$ but which is not in $\mathfrak{a}$.

I don't know how to follow... I don't know if I'm going from the right way... Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: an element is invertible iff the ideal it generates is the whole ring.

Comment: Also you may wanna correct your first sentence, a ring is local if it only has one maximal ideal.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have tried to use that but I don't reach to any conclusion... @Nissokam What can I do with that?

Comment: Can you see why an invertible element cannot be in any maximal ideal?

Comment: mmm.. I'm not sure.. Can you expalin me? @Nissokam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every element outside the maximal ideal of a local ring is a unit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546573/every-element-outside-the-maximal-ideal-of-a-local-ring-is-a-unit) Or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102372/r-local-ring-i-maximal-ideal-then-x-notin-i-implies-x-unit)?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\notin \mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ is the only maximal ideal, then there is no maximal ideal containing $x$.

Consider all ideals containing $x$ and not containing $1$.

If this set is empty, then $1$ is in the ideal $xA$ generated by $x$. This implies that there is $a\in A$ such that $1=ax$ and then $x$ is a unit.

If this set is non-empty you can apply Zorn's lemma to get a maximal element by inclusion. Observe that a maximal element $I$ of this set is also a maximal ideal of $A$. This is because if $I\subset J\subset A$ we would have $x\in J$ and if $J\neq A$, then $1\notin J$. Therefore, $J=I$.

Since $\mathfrak{a}$ is the only maximal ideal and $x\notin \mathfrak{a}$, such a maximal ideal $I\ni x$ cannot exist.

Comment: Why have you chosen the ideal $xA$?

Comment: @User160 The ideal $xA$ contains $x$ and the condition of $x$ being a unit is equivalent to $1\in xA$. So, $xA$ is related to what we want to prove. Moreover, since $xA$ is an ideal it gives us a way to relate it to maximal ideals of $A$, which is what the hypothesis is about.

Comment: If you don’t want to use Zorn’s Lemma, observe that for $x$ not a unit, $A / (x)$ is not the zero ring, hence has a maximal ideal $V$, which by the correspondence theorem corresponds to a maximal ideal $U$ of $A$ which contains $x$. Though of course you still need Zorn’s Lemma for the fact that nonzero rings have a maximal ideal.

Comment: @User160 That every nonunit $\,n\,$ has a max($\Rightarrow$ prime) ideal container ("divisor") $P$
is an ideal-theoretic generalization of: every nonunit integer $\,n\,$ has a prime divisor $\,p\,$ ([recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1291435/242) contains = divides for principal ideals $\,P=(p)\supseteq (a)\iff p\mid a)\ \ $